# how insert csv data to mongodb with nodejs

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mongodb, csv

Hi im developing an app with nodeJS, express and a mongoDB, i need to take users data from a csv file and upload it to my database this db has a schema designed with mongoose.

but i don know how to do this, what is the best approach to read the csv file check for duplicates against the db and if the user (one column in the csv) is not here insert it?

are there some module to do this? or i need to build it from scratch? im pretty new to nodeJS
i need a few advices here

Thanks

this app have an angular frontend so the user can upload the file, maybe i should read the csv in the front end and transform it into an array for node, then insert it?

Comment: there are easy to use npm libraries for both csv data and mongodb.

Comment: @gary:Have you completed the task?

Answer (score 5):

Use one of the several node.js csv libraries like [this one](https://github.com/wdavidw/node-csv), and then you can probably just run an [upsert](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) on the user name.

An upsert is an update query with the upsert flag set to true: `{upsert: true}`.  This will insert a new record only if the search returns zero results.  So you query may look something like this:

```
 db.collection.update({username: userName}, newDocumentObj, {upsert: true})
```

Where `userName` is the current username you're working with and `newDocumentObj` is the json document that may need to be inserted.

However, if the query does return a result, it performs an update on those records.

EDIT:
I've decided that an upsert is not appropriate for this but I'm going to leave the description.

You're probably going to need to do two queries here, a find and a conditional insert.  For this find query I'd use the `toArray()` function (instead of a stream) since you are expecting 0 or 1 results.  Check if you got a result on the username and if not insert the data.

Read about node's mongodb library [here](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native).

EDIT in response to your comment:
It looks like you're reading data from a local csv file, so you should be able to structure you program like:

```
function connect(callback) {
    connStr = 'mongodb://' + host + ':' + port + '/' + schema;  //command line args, may or may not be needed, hard code if not I guess
    MongoClient.connect(connStr, function(err, db) {
        if(err) {
            callback(err, null);
        } else {
            colObj = db.collection(collection); //command line arg, hard code if not needed
            callback(null, colObj);
        }
    });
}

connect(function(err, colObj) {
    if(err) {
        console.log('Error:', err.stack);
        process.exit(0);
    } else {
        console.log('Connected');
        doWork(colObj, function(err) {
            if(err) {
                console.log(err.stack);
                process.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }
});


function doWork(colObj, callback) {
    csv().from('/path/to/file.csv').on('data', function(data) {
        //mongo query(colObj.find) for data.username or however the data is structured
        //inside callback for colObj.find, check for results, if no results insert data with colObj.insert, callback for doWork inside callback for insert or else of find query check
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info Jake, so first i just have to parse the csv row into an json with the help of some libraries? you have done that before?

Comment: Thanks Jake! you are using a library to handle the csv here?

Comment: @Gary Please upvote my answer if it helped and accept it if you believe I have fully answered your question.

Comment: relax i will, but right now i dont have enought points, im new in this site =)

Comment: Gary you don't have to have enough points to accept an answer.  You should accept this answer as correct answer.